# Can't Select Customized Combobox Items (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Two problems that I'm having with Vuetify's combobox:

1. Input is cleared on blur (combobox not focused on) and I don't want this. This doesn't happen if I don't customize how my items look with v-slot:item though.
2. Can't select any of the items when I'm trying to customize my items with v-slot:item, but I can select them if I don't customize the items.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong when I basically just copied straight from the documentation and adjusted it to my needs.

```
  <v-combobox
    @focus="isShaped = true"
    @blur="isShaped = false"
    v-model="card_name"
    :loading="isLoading"
    :items="cards"
    hide-no-data
    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
    append-icon=""
    outlined rounded :shaped="isShaped"
    label="Search for a card"
    :search-input.sync="search"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="set_name"
  >
    <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title class="mb-2">{{item.name}}</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle>{{item.set_name}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
      <span v-text="item.name"></span>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:progress>
      <v-progress-circular
        class="mt-3"
        v-if="isLoading"
        indeterminate
        color="primary"
        :width="2"
        :size="30"
      ></v-progress-circular>
    </template>
  </v-combobox>
```

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/chataolauj/pen/RwwYxBg?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

For both the issues you have to provide the props to the template and then bind them.

```
<template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
  <v-list-item v-bind="props">
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title class="mb-2">{{item.name}}</v-list-item-title>
      <v-list-item-subtitle>{{item.set_name}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</template>

<template v-slot:selection="{ props, item }">
  <span v-bind="props" v-text="item.name"></span>
</template>
```